# How to upload content via Github API to hidden folder name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I am trying to upload a Github action workflow via the Github V3 API.

I am trying to do the following to upload the `main.yaml` file to `.github/workflows/main.yaml`:

```
await this.put(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.ownerName}/${this.repoName}/contents/.github/workflows/main.yaml`, {
  message: title,
  content,
  sha,
  branch: newBranch
})
```

It seems as though including the `.github` in the file path of the URL returns a 404. Is it possible to upload to a hidden directory? Maybe I need to escape the `.` somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It might be that used personal access token (PAT) has insufficient permissions.
Slightly unintuitive, but to upload workflow files, the PAT needs to have a "Workflow" scope enabled too, not only have a write access to repo.

It is at [tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens/) and looks like:

[image]

Comment: damnit lost so much time because of this... thanks @arturas

Comment: This was precisely my issue - banging my head and opening support requests with GitHub when it was this all along. In my case it was not a PAT but an OAuth token created with only the `repo` scope required... #facepalm