# How to create git tree with nested directories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

Via Github's API, I want to commit a file that is nested 2 files deep i.e. `.github/workflows/main.yaml`.

When I do the following, I get a 404 not found error response

```
const createTree = ({
  ownerName,
  repoName,
  masterSha,
  sha
}) => {
  return axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
    base_tree: masterSha,
    tree: [
      {
        path: ".github/workflows/main.yaml",
        mode: "100644", 
        type: "blob",
        sha
      }
    ]
  })  
})
```

If I set path to `workflows/main.yaml` it seems to work fine.

How do I create a tree within subdirectories?

Comment: I just answered a question which is almost the same as your question! See step 3 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68075323/11145447 and the detailed explanation of steps two and three below that.

Comment: You may also want to confirm that the token you are using has the "workflow" scope - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064458/how-to-upload-content-via-github-api-to-hidden-folder-name. I wasted hours trying to debug a 404 when uploading a workflow file because of the missing scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to create the file tree first and then create the directory tree from the file tree sha.

This is the code that worked for me

```
const createTree = ({
  ownerName,
  repoName,
  masterSha,
  sha
}) => {
  // Create main.yaml file in workflows/main.yaml
  const { tree } = await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
    base_tree: masterSha,
    tree: [
      {
        path: "workflows/main.yaml",
        mode: "100644", 
        type: "blob",
        sha
      }
    ]
  })  

  const workflowTree = tree.find(t => t.path === "workflows");

  // Create .github directory from the previous tree sha
  await axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${ownerName}/${repoName}/git/trees`, {
    base_tree: masterSha,
    tree: [
      {
        path: ".github/workflows",
        mode: workflowTree.mode, // "040000"
        type: workflowTree.type, // "tree"
        sha: workflowTree.sha 
      }
    ]
  })
})
```